# how can i convert a video into image files using ffmpeg in c#?

Tags: c#

```
        string inputpath = strFileNamePath;
        string outputpath = "C:\\Image\\";
        //for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < 1000; iIndex++)
        //{
            //string fileargs = "-i" + " " + inputpath + "  -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 200 -r 15 -s 320x240 -f flv " + outputpath + "SRT.flv";
            string fileargs = "-i" + " " + inputpath + " " + outputpath + "image.jpg";
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Badr\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\Video2image2video.\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.Start();
```

i have this code this creates only 1 image of video i apply a loop but i repeatedly generates the initial image how can i get images of all the video

thanx in advance

Comment: Please try to avoid hard coded paths, c:\\documents etc is horrifying. Use 'System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)' To get the path in which the exe is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html):

> You can extract images from a video,
>   or create a video from many images:
>
> For extracting images from a video:
>
> ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f
>   image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
>
> This will extract one video frame per
>   second from the video and will output
>   them in files named `foo-001.jpeg',`
>   foo-002.jpeg', etc. Images will be
>   rescaled to fit the new WxH values.

So just change the arguments you pass to ffmpeg and you should be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Hi do you want to take images in video files when you for to return in in this way;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < iImageCount; i++)
                                {

                                   string sInputVideo = Page.MapPath(...);

                                   string sImageCapture = Page.MapPath("") + "\\Videolar\\"  + ImageName+ "_" + iResim + ".jpg";

                                    ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i \"" + sInputVideo + "\" -s 108*100 -ss " + iImageCapture + " -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg \"" + sImageCapture + "\"";
                                    ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = (Server.MapPath("Referanslar/ffmpeg.exe"));
                                    ffmpeg.Start();
                                    ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
                                    ffmpeg.Close();
                                    iImageCapture += 1;
                                    iResim++;
                                }
```

You can take pictures as you like by changing it ;)